# Excel Macro for transposing data based on a coloumn

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel vb scripting. I am trying to copy values from a number of rows of an excel sheet, depending upon a value (prpId) in another coloumn. There are multiple 'prpId' and for each of these there are multiple values in another column, which too I need to check and if the second condition also matches, copy whatever value is present in the adjacent column of the same row to another cell.

The code I wrote is:

```
Sub TransData()
Dim prpId As long
prpId = 100011;
Dim prpIdRng As long
Dim i As long
i = 2
    While Cells(ActiveCell.Count, "a").Row <> Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row 
        While (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "a").Value = prpId and Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "a").Value = "")
            If (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "f").Value = "Co") then
                Set Cells(i, "k").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value  
                        ElseIf (Cells(i, "f").Value = "He")) then
                Set Cells(i, "l").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value 
                        ElseIf (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "f").Value = "A") then
                Set Cells(i, "m").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value 
                        ElseIf (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "f").Value = "B") then
                Set Cells(i, "n").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value 
                        ElseIf (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "f").Value = "C") then
                Set Cells(i, "o").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value 
                        ElseIf (Cells((ActiveCell.Row, "f").Value = "D") then
                Set Cells(i, "p").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value 
                        ElseIf (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "f").Value = "E") then
                Set Cells(i, "q").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value 
            End If
            ActiveCell.Row = ActiveCell.Row+1
        Wend
        prpId = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "a").Value     
        i = i+1
    Wend
```

When I run this I am getting a run time error. Can someone please help.

Comment: What's the error and what line does it occur on?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Row = ActiveCell.Row+1` This at least will cause an error, you cannot change the active cell this way.  Instead, try `activecell.offset(1,0).activate` .  You really should avoid selecting cells in VBA , but for the purposes of this project i recommend you try that change, and also tell us what the error message you are getting says, and what line it appears on -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a couple of syntax errors and runtime errors whilst trying to run this code,

I tweaked a few brackets and fixed the row issue that @Acantud mentioned:

```
Sub TransData()
Dim prpId As Long
prpId = (100011)
Dim prpIdRng As Long
Dim i As Long
i = 2
    While Cells(ActiveCell.Count, "a").Row <> Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
        While (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "a").Value = prpId And Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "a").Value = "")
            If (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "f").Value = "Co") Then
                Set Cells(i, "k").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value
                        ElseIf (Cells(i, "f").Value = "He") Then
                Set Cells(i, "l").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value
                        ElseIf (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "f").Value = "A") Then
                Set Cells(i, "m").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value
                        ElseIf (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "f").Value = "B") Then
                Set Cells(i, "n").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value
                        ElseIf (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "f").Value = "C") Then
                Set Cells(i, "o").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value
                        ElseIf (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "f").Value = "D") Then
                Set Cells(i, "p").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value
                        ElseIf (Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "f").Value = "E") Then
                Set Cells(i, "q").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value
            End If
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        Wend
        prpId = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "a").Value
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```